# Pandas index error running apply function

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, apply

I have created the following function:

```
def stripnum(str): 
    array = re.findall(r'\d+', str) 
    return array[0]
```

Testing this function on a single row works perfectly fine.

```
stripnum(dataset.loc[4,'Description']) 
>> 11
```

Now I would like to apply this function to an existing column and create a new column:

```
dataset['Reason'] = dataset['Description'].apply(stripnum)
```

But unfortunately, I get an error 
`list index out of range`. 
Running `dataset.info()` I retrieve the information that the rangeIndex is 1366, 0 to 1365.
The column `Description` has 1366 elements. So I am confused, why I receive this error.

I have tried to create a new index column with:

```
dataset['Index'] = range(1,len(dataset)+1)
```

but the problem remains.

Is there a smart way to solve this issue ?

Comment: What happens if you call `stripnum('')` or `stripnum('ABC')`? The problem is with your function.

Comment: What’s the point of using `findall()` if you only ever care about the first match?

Comment: Also, it’s unclear what exactly your function is meant to do. Can you clarify that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Unless you are confident that every row value of the column you are passing to function is non-empty and has digit value*, it may be problem with your function. What happens if there is no digit in string and what is value of array? 
Suppose you try to use `findall` as above in string value `ABC`:

```
array = re.findall(r'\d+', "ABC") 
array
```

Output will be `[]`.

And if you try to access empty array it would give error. You can try the following:

```
def stripnum(string_val): 
    array = re.findall(r'\d+', string_val) 
    if array: # <-- Checking if array is not empty
        return array[0]
    else:     # <-- array is empty then return None
        return None
```

**Note**: I changed `str` to `string_val` as `str` is built-in type name.

Comment: Darn ! You are of course right, as I have simply assumed that a number is contained in this column. Expanding the function with the conditional statement fixes the issue. Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Great! `Happy Coding`.